# first video in array is always first or second to play on next video function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, video

I have a video array set up, and a set of six thumbs that each correspond with a video in the array to play it, and then a function calling for the next to be played. Instead of playing the next video when it ends however, it goes to play the first video in the array, then goes through the list.

I have the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nata2ha/kTuEy/8/) so you can see exactly what I mean.
 And then how can I make it stop looping when it reaches the end. (I'm sure this is simple, but I'm suffering from severe lack of sleep and a deadline)

Comment: +1 for using jsfiddle, cats and apples to lure people into watching a video about Jesus...

Comment: @RichardTowers omg, I didn't realize, it was from another example... it's the echo one, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're always passing 0 to your `playArray` callback.

This fiddle works, but it stores the index in a higher scope which you were probably trying to avoid: http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/WFT3U/1/

A simple way to stop looping when you reach the end, just don't call `load` and `play`: http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/WFT3U/2/.

Comment: actually, I just changed `index = 0` to `index = i` and this works perfect, thank you!